# Flutter auto OTP with firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebas auth with Phone

```
    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        var sms = credential.smsCode;

        logger.i('sms: $sms');
      },
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
        completer.completeError(
            e.message ?? 'Unknown Error occurred with code : ${e.code}');
      },
      codeSent: (verificationId, forceResendingToken) {
        completer.complete();
        codeSent(verificationId, forceResendingToken);
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
        logger.i('verificationId: $verificationId');
      },
    );
```

And I want to implement auto OTP capture inside my app 
so I used this package [sms_autofill](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_autofill) 
but it requires me to send the app signature along with the sent SMS to be able to retreive the OTP code from it so I can verify it with firebase auth, 
but I can't change the SMS template in firebase to implement my app signature, 
So what to do!

Comment: You may have to consider using third-party providers like Twilio for your sms